# Rakefile autoconf equivalent

Tags: ruby, makefile, rake, rakefile

I'm planning on using rake to replace my existing Makefile setup; while building everything is fine, is there an equivalent of autoconf's ./configure script(s)?

I don't want to start rolling my own if there's something already out there, but I couldn't see anything from searching.

This is for the purpose of testing system headers, etc., to ensure the system being built for is suitable, the correct paths are known, and so forth. I can handle the --with-ssl style options without a problem, it's things like the stdbool.h being available I'm after. I'm building on BSDs and Linux, and there's obviously a fair few differences...

Comment: In such case, you could leverage rake itself with a different task for the purpose of configuration. In such "configuration" task you can do any house-clean task that you need to.